# Replicating Raspberry Pi OS with Yocto

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, yocto

Raspberry Pi OS makes it very easy to experiment with Raspberry Pi and Linux.

Will to have a system with your own customizations built for you automatically, however, leads you to using Yocto.

Is there any straight-forward way to add elements like the desktop environment and raspi-config tool of Raspberry Pi OS to Yocto? Which image should I use as base and what should I add?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question does fit better in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ Here are only a few people with Yocto experience, and probably even less knowing what »Pi OS« is.

Comment: Good point. I didn't know there is such site. I will repost this there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted this same question at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/140011/replicating-raspberry-pi-os-using-yocto .

I didn't know about that site when I posted this here and I don't know which one is more suitable for this, but I am not thinking of putting there a link back here so I am kind of directing the discussion there.